# Calculate price with decimals

Tags: jquery

I am working on a script to calculate the price for surface, like 'm2'. Below is my script, but what I want is that the euros are with 2 decimals. How can I fix this? I have tried parseFloat() and toFixed(2) but I think it's not past in the right place.

```
var surface;
var totalPrice;

function calculateSurface() {
    var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;

    surface = length * width;
} 


function calculatePrice() {
    var area = $('#area').val();

    if(area=='pur3') {
        totalPrice = surface * 16;
    }

    else if(area=='pur4') {
        totalPrice = surface * 17.50;
    }

    else if(area=='pur5') {
        totalPrice = surface * 19;
    }

    else if(area=='pur6') {
        totalPrice = surface * 21;
    }

    else if(area=='pur7') {
        totalPrice = surface * 23.50;
    }

}

function showResults() {
    return surface + '  ' + totalPrice;
}


$("#calc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateSurface();
    calculatePrice();   
    $('.result').html('Aantal oppervlakte: ' + surface + ' m&sup2;' + '<br>' + '&euro; ' + totalPrice + '' );

});
```

Comment: Quick tip: When dealing with money, *always* works in cents (pennies, or whatever smallest equivalent your currency has). Integer math is precise. Then, when displaying, you can divide by 100 and use `toFixed(2)`... or you can just splice in the `.` two characters from the end ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol But where should I use `toFixed(2)` than? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was said, your should only round when printing anything. Keep the real calculation values at all times to avoid loss of precision. In fact, when saving your data, you should save the parameters and not only the results, as you can always recalculate with the raw arguments if it needs be.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sdyk/) as example :

```
var areaBasePrice = {
  'pur3': 16,
  'pur4': 17.50,
  'pur5': 19,
  'pur6': 21,
  'pur7': 23.5
};

function calculateSurface() {
  var length = $("#length").val();
  var width = $("#width").val();

  return length * width;
} 

function calculatePrice() {
  var area = $('#area').val();

  return areaBasePrice[area] * calculateSurface();
}

$("#calc").click(function(e) {
    var surface = calculateSurface();
    var price = calculatePrice();

    $('.result').html('Aantal oppervlakte: ' + surface + ' m&sup2;' + '<br>' + '&euro; ' + price.toFixed(2) );

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

#### Edit

Just a note on loss of precision with floating values. Unless you are working for a banking company with many critical transactions, you should *really* not be concerned about rounding to a hundreth of a value (up or down). If you do, then send your parameters server side and/or use a proper currency manipulation library for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Like Niet mentionned before, use integers for money dealing. Binary numbers cant accurately represent some float numbers ( .20 ending numbers come to mind).

So all of your values become your previous value * 100, so:

```
if(area=='pur3') {
    totalPrice = surface * 1600;
}

else if(area=='pur4') {
    totalPrice = surface * 1750;
}

else if(area=='pur5') {
    totalPrice = surface * 1900;
}

else if(area=='pur6') {
    totalPrice = surface * 2100;
}

else if(area=='pur7') {
    totalPrice = surface * 2350;
}
```

Then when you show the price, you divide by 100 and fix it to 2 decimals:

```
$("#calc").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  calculateSurface();
  calculatePrice();
  var fixedPrice = (totalPrice/100).toFixed(2);
  $('.result').html('Aantal oppervlakte: ' + surface + ' m&sup2;' + '<br>' + '&euro; ' + fixedPrice + '' );
});
```

Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to force 2 decimal places, `.toFixed()` will not help you with numbers that don't require that precision (ie. 3.5).  I created a JSFiddle for this scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/f38ww/3/

Updated JS:

```
function formatCurrency ( number ) {
    return Math.floor(number) + '.' + (Math.floor(number % 1 * 100) || '00');
}

function calculateSurface() {
    return $('#length').val() * $('#width').val();
}

function calculatePrice(surface) {
    var lookup = {
        pur3: 16,     pur4: 17.5,
        pur5: 19,     pur6: 21,
        pur7: 23.5
    };
    return surface * lookup[$('#area').val()];
}

$("#calc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var surface = calculateSurface(),
        price = calculatePrice(surface);
    $('.result').html(
        'Aantal oppervlakte: ' + surface +
        ' m&sup2;<br>&euro; ' + formatCurrency(price)
    );
});
```